# Should the search engine return a dictionary or strongly typed objects?

Tags: c#, code-reviews, domain-driven-design, code-reuse

I'm building a search engine using Lucene.NET / Solr.NET, and I'm wondering should search hits be returned as a dictionary or strongly typed object.

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchHits { get; set; }
    ...
}

// where search hit looks like this
Dictionary<string, object> searchHit = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Name", "John Doe" },
    { "Address", "Some street" },
};
```

vs

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> SearchHits { get; set; }
    ...
}

// where search hit looks like this
var searchHit = new SearchHit
{
    Name = "John Doe",
    Address = "Some address"
};
```

I will be indexing different types of objects (People, Web pages, Files, etc.).
Each object has a different set of properties (people have name and address, while web pages have URLs and titles), and search hits don't have the same set of properties as original objects (`WebPage` class has the `MainContent` property, but after indexing, the search hit that represents this object will have the `PreviewText` property (the first 300 characters of `MainContent` property with stripped HTML tags).

I don't want to duplicate the code all over the place and have: `IPeopleSearchService`, `IWebPagesSearchService`, `IFilesSearchService`, etc. and corresponding search results: `PeopleSearchResult`, `FileSearchResult`, etc.

```
interface IFooService
{
    FooSearchResult Search(string text);
    void Index(Foo foo);
    ...
}

interface IBarService
{
    BarSearchResult Search(string text);
    void Index(Bar bar);
    ...
}
...
```

I would like to have a more generic solution, but I don't like over-complexity. It should be readable and easily understandable by junior developer.

```
interface ISearchService<TEntity, TSearchHit>
{
    SearchResult<TSearchHit> Search(string text);
    void Index(TEntity entity);
}
```

How would you design such a system? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, what's wrong with the generic interface you posted? It doesn't look overly complex to me.

Comment: For every `TEntity` I have to define `TSearchHit`. Does this look like overkill? Would I benefit from returning a `Dictionary` instead of `TSearchHit`?

Comment: Or can I just have one search service that has `Dictionary<string, object> Search (string text, IEntityMappingStrategy mapper)` and `void Index (object entity, IEntityMappingStrategy mapper)` methods, and then define / instantiate different strategies for each entity? Would that be more SOLID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're asking is: should I make the search results statically typed? I think the answer depends on what you're going to do with them and how much do you like static typing.

Regarding what you're going to do: if you're just going to display the results to the user, or something like that that treats all the fields in the search result equally, then using a `Dictionary` (which is basically the same as dynamic typing) makes sense. On the other hand, if you're often going to write things like `searchHist.Address` (or `searchHit["Address"]`), then that points more to static typing.

Regarding how much you like static typing: to me, as a proponent of static typing, using dynamic typing gives you small short term advantage (e.g. you don't have to write those dozen lines declaring each `TSearchHit`) for significant long term disadvantages (no compiler checking for typos, no IntelliSense). This means that I think static typing is almost always worth the up-front cost. Proponents of dynamic typing would tell you otherwise, but C# is mostly statically typed language, and presumably you're using that for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Lucene.NET / Solr.NET but it look to me that a solution for this would be to use generic types:

```
public class SearchResult<TEntity>
{
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, TEntity>> SearchHits { get; set; }
    ...
}

interface ISearchService<TEntity>
{
    SearchResult<TEntity> Search(string text);
    void Index<TEntity>(TEntity entity);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The question says the type of the search result is different from the type of the normal entity.